# Oracle SQL query returns same set of results despite variation in ROWNUM value

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm working on a Oracle/PHP application and trying to implement a "load-more" functionality.

Here are the two tables and their structures:

`questions:`
`id (int) | title (varchar(999)) | datetime (varchar(999))`

`questions_tags:`
`id (int) | question_id (int) | tag_id (int)`

The following is the code in index.php:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select * from (
                              select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from (
                                  SELECT questions.id FROM questions_tags, questions WHERE 
                                      questions.id = questions_tags.question_id AND
                                      questions_tags.tag_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ORDER BY questions.datetime ASC
                              ) a where rownum <= 10
                          ) where rnum >= 0");
oci_execute($stid);
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
    // Do work with the results
}
```

The following is the javascript behind it:

```
$("#load_more").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadMore.php?x=" + $(".span_data:last").data("id"),
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                // append data
            } else {
                // remove button
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
```

Finally, here is the loadMore.php file:

```
<?php
$x = $_GET['x'];
$xTen = intval($x) + 10;
$count_id = $x;

try
{
    $lastID = 0;
    $tagIDs = implode("','", $user_tag_ids);
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select * from (
                                  select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from (
                                      SELECT questions.id FROM questions_tags, questions WHERE
                                          questions.id = questions_tags.question_id AND
                                          questions_tags.tag_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ORDER by questions.datetime DESC
                              ) a where rownum <= $xTen
                          ) where rnum >= $x");
    oci_execute($stid);
    while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
        // Do work with the results
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    print "Error";
}
?>
```

No matter what the value of `x` is, the `loadMore.php` file continues to return the same set of results. So if I do `/loadMore.php?x=10`, I will get the same results as that returned by `/loadMore.php?x=100` However, if I go even further (`/loadMore.php?x=1500`), that's when I finally get different results. I can't understand what's going wrong here.

**As I said in the comments:**

If I remove all the `rownum` parameters and just run

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM questions_tags WHERE 
        questions.id = questions_tags.question_id AND 
        questions_tags.tag_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
) ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

I get all the results, probably a thousand rows. I'm trying to get the first 10 of those thousand rows and then keep getting the next 10 when the user clicks the "load more" button. That's why I have same query index.php and loadMore.php

Comment: Is `questions.datetime` unique?  If your `ORDER BY` does not produce a unique order, it's entirely possible that a row would get a different `ROWNUM` on subsequent executions even with the same parameters.  In other words, if "the first 10" isn't well-defined because there are hundreds of rows with the same `datetime` value, your approach isn't going to work well.

Comment: `datetime` is not unique. If I remove all the rownum parameters and just run the `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM questions_tags WHERE questions.id = questions_tags.question_id AND questions_tags.tag_id IN ('$tagIDs'))ORDER BY datetime DESC` query, I get all the results, probably a thousand rows. What I'm pretty much trying to do is get the first 10 of those thousand rows and then keep getting the next 10 when the user clicks the "load more" button. That's why I have same query `index.php` and `loadMore.php`

Comment: If you want an ordering that you can rely upon, then you need to include enough columns in your ORDER BY clause such that the combination of all of those columns is unique for each row. Nothing else is guaranteed.

Comment: You could likely get rid of the outermost query and on the first inner query use something like `WHERE rownum BETWEEN $x and $xTen`. Also, sql injection warning. You intval $x when adding 10, but not when getting the initial value. And lastly, that will return 11 rows, not 10. You likely want to either subtract 1 from `$xTen` or switch the `<= $xTen` to `< $xTen`. Leave the `>=` on the `$x` comparison.

Comment: Just reading and I see the way you are doing is supposed to be the optimal solution. I work with Oracle all day but haven't had to do pagination in it for a while as we typically don't have large lists.

Comment: No, sorry, I made a mistake. As for your problem, I would suggest echo'ing out the query and running it in sqlplus/sql developer (whatever you use for your database) and compare the results. From reading over your query it should do what you are expecting and appears to be correct unless you are getting something like duplicate rows from the join. You would get the same question.id duplicated for every tag on the question. So 3 tags would make the query show the same question.id 3 times. Maybe add distinct to the inner query or instead of the join do a sub-query.

Comment: Typically you don't join if you are not using any columns from the join table (selecting a column or using the column to join another table) and can do it in a where clause. Using a sub-query will offer better performance.

Comment: To fix this issue, all I had to was add an additional column to `Order By` clause: `ORDER BY questions.datetime DESC, questions.id DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I realized that `ORDER BY questions.datetime` wasn't unique enough to sort the result properly. Changing the query to `ORDER BY questions.datetime DESC, questions.id DESC` fixed the issue and began to show unique results.